# why is my Activity being logcat="WIN DEATH Killing ProcessRecord" when i mount sd card to computer

Tags: android, android-intent

My `Activity` have the `android.intent.action.SEND` in the manifest so
i select an image in the Android `Gallery` and my `Activity` open right.

If i select from the `Notification` menu to mount the phone
to the computer the `Activity` is being killed by the system.

```
Force stopping package de.android_telefonie.appmanager uid=10111   
Force stopping package com.twoplay.twoplayer uid=10083             
Force stopping package com.spritefish.fastburstcameralite uid=10086
Force stopping package org.openintents.filemanager uid=10077       
Force stopping package com.google.zxing.client.android uid=10071   
Force stopping package com.domobile.efile uid=10081                
Force stopping package com.google.android.apps.shopper uid=10067
```

What can i be doing wrong?

***UPDATE***
MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.carlsberg.holta" 
          android:versionCode="1"       
          android:versionName="0.52"   
          android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <permission android:name="com.carlsberg.holta.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" 
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />

      <uses-permission android:name="com.carlsberg.holta.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/launcher" android:label="@string/string_app_name">

        <activity android:name=".ActivityMainLauncher" 
                  android:label="@string/string_app_name"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop"
                  android:icon="@drawable/launcher">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                    <data android:mimeType="video/*" /> 
                    <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                    <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
                    <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                    <data android:mimeType="video/*" /> 
                    <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                    <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
                    <data android:mimeType="application/*" />               

            </intent-filter>  
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>    

        <activity android:name=".gallery.ActivityGallery" 
                  android:icon="@drawable/launcher_gallery"
                  android:label="@string/string_app_name_gallery"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                  android:taskAffinity="com.carlsberg.holta.GalleryActivity"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop"    >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


       <activity android:name=".send.ActivitySend"
                    android:launchMode="singleTask"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">

        </activity>     

        <activity android:name=".ActivityRemoveFriend"
                  android:label="@string/string_app_name" 
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">       

        </activity> 

        <activity android:name="com.carlsberg.holta.history.TabActivityHistoryLauncher"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask"
                  android:label="@string/string_app_name" 
                  >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.carlsberg.holta.history.ActivityTabGroup1"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.carlsberg.holta.history.ActivityTabGroup2"></activity> 

        <activity android:name="com.carlsberg.holta.history.ActivityHistoryOutgoing"></activity>                     
        <activity android:name="com.carlsberg.holta.history.ActivityHistoryIncoming"></activity> 

        <activity android:name=".ActivityLogin" 
                  android:label="@string/string_app_name" 
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityAddFriend" 
                  android:label="@string/string_app_name" 
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>   

        <activity android:name=".ActivityAcceptFriend"             
                  android:label="@string/string_app_name" 
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<!--         <activity android:name=".GalleryView">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> -->
        <service android:name=".IntentServiceSendFiles" android:label="@string/string_sendFileService">
<!--            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.Hasse.holta.SendFileService">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>   -->      
         </service>
        <service android:name=".IntentServiceGetFiles" android:label="@string/string_getFileService">

         </service> 
        <service android:name=".ServiceBootCompleated" android:label="@string/string_batchtester">

         </service>                  
        <service android:name=".C2DMReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
                <intent-filter>
                        <!-- Receive the actual message -->
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                        <category android:name="com.carlsberg.holta" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                        <!-- Receive the registration id -->
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                        <category android:name="com.carlsberg.holta" />
                </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
            <receiver  android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".myBroadcastReceiver">  
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
            </intent-filter>  
        </receiver>

        <provider android:name=".contentprovider.UserContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.carlsberg.holta.contentprovider" >
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**UPDATE** 
The ActivitySend is my class. You'll see it OnStart(), OnResume()
then I mount the SD card and the killing begins.
(just restarted the phone to eliminate cache problem)

```
DEBUG/SwitchUsbSettings(367): getUpdateInfo() no update
DEBUG/SwitchUsbSettings(367): -enableDiskDrive()
INFO/global(367): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
DEBUG/SwitchUsbSettings(367): usb_cable_connect = 1
INFO/PackageManager(113): Updating external media status from mounted to unmounted
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec list
INFO/LSState(113): EventReceiver:android.intent.action.NOTIFICATION_UPDATE
DEBUG/AK8973(72): Compass Start
DEBUG/Sensors(113): open_akm, fd=106
DEBUG/Sensors(113): close_akm, fd=106
DEBUG/NetSharing_NSReceiver(346): onReceive : INTENT_DISK
DEBUG/UsbConnectedReceiver(367): action = com.htc.android.ackISOFF
DEBUG/UsbConnectedReceiver(367): Received intent:com.htc.android.ackISOFF
DEBUG/ActivitySend(1119): onStart ***********************************************************************
DEBUG/ActivitySend(1119): onResume ***********************************************************************
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec path android.androidVNC-1
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec path org.openintents.filemanager-1
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec path de.android_telefonie.appmanager-1
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec path org.cohortor.gstrings-2
DEBUG/AK8973(72): Compass CLOSE 
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec path com.easyshare.android-1
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec path com.twoplay.twoplayer-2
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec path com.google.android.apps.shopper-1
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec path radioenergy.app-2
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec path com.carlsberg.PTPPService-1
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec path com.domobile.efile-2
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec path com.spritefish.fastburstcameralite-2
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec path com.google.zxing.client.android-2
INFO/PackageManager(113): Removing non-system package:com.google.zxing.client.android
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package com.google.zxing.client.android uid=10071
DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(113): Layer::setBuffers(this=0x7713b0), pid=1119, w=480, h=800
DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(113): Layer::setBuffers(this=0x7713b0), pid=1119, w=480, h=800
DEBUG/SlidingDrawerLeftOptions(1119): handleHeight: 400
DEBUG/SlidingDrawerLeftFriends(1119): handleHeight: 132
DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(113): Layer::requestBuffer(this=0x7713b0), index=0, pid=1119, w=480, h=800 success
WARN/InputManagerService(113): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@466de6e0 (uid=10001 pid=367)
DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(113): Layer::requestBuffer(this=0x7713b0), index=1, pid=1119, w=480, h=800 success
INFO/PackageManager(113): Removing non-system package:radioenergy.app
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package radioenergy.app uid=10068
INFO/PackageManager(113): Removing non-system package:de.android_telefonie.appmanager
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package de.android_telefonie.appmanager uid=10111
VERBOSE/AlarmManager(113): Alarm triggering: Alarm{463fde98 type 2 com.fring}
VERBOSE/AlarmManager(113): Adding Alarm{463fde98 type 2 com.fring} jan 01 01:05:10 f.m.
INFO/PackageManager(113): Removing non-system package:android.androidVNC
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package android.androidVNC uid=10058
INFO/PackageManager(113): Removing non-system package:org.cohortor.gstrings
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package org.cohortor.gstrings uid=10064
INFO/PackageManager(113): Removing non-system package:com.spritefish.fastburstcameralite
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package com.spritefish.fastburstcameralite uid=10086
INFO/PackageManager(113): Removing non-system package:com.twoplay.twoplayer
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package com.twoplay.twoplayer uid=10083
INFO/PackageManager(113): Removing non-system package:com.easyshare.android
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package com.easyshare.android uid=10104
INFO/PackageManager(113): Removing non-system package:com.domobile.efile
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package com.domobile.efile uid=10081
INFO/PackageManager(113): Removing non-system package:com.google.android.apps.shopper
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package com.google.android.apps.shopper uid=10067
INFO/PackageManager(113): Removing non-system package:org.openintents.filemanager
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package org.openintents.filemanager uid=10077
DEBUG/dalvikvm(113): JIT code cache reset in 8 ms (1048528 bytes 1/0)
DEBUG/dalvikvm(113): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 40848 objects / 2270952 bytes in 147ms
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package com.google.zxing.client.android uid=10071
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package radioenergy.app uid=10068
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package de.android_telefonie.appmanager uid=10111
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package android.androidVNC uid=10058
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package org.cohortor.gstrings uid=10064
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package com.spritefish.fastburstcameralite uid=10086
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package com.twoplay.twoplayer uid=10083
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package com.easyshare.android uid=10104
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package com.domobile.efile uid=10081
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package com.google.android.apps.shopper uid=10067
INFO/ActivityManager(113): Force stopping package org.openintents.filemanager uid=10077
DEBUG/dalvikvm(269): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5940 objects / 304472 bytes in 82ms
DEBUG/dalvikvm(273): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8096 objects / 453824 bytes in 101ms
DEBUG/HomeLoaders(273): load applications
DEBUG/HomeLoaders(273): loading user items
DEBUG/HomeLoaders(273):   --> starting workspace loader
DEBUG/RosieDbDebug(273): startLoaders(true)
DEBUG/HomeLoaders(273): Remove temporary ItemInfo : screen < 0 OR cellX < 0 OR cellY < 0 
DEBUG/HomeLoaders(273): get install or remove message so do change adapter
DEBUG/dalvikvm(113): GC_EXPLICIT freed 14816 objects / 1049576 bytes in 100ms
DEBUG/HomeLoaders(273): Locale changed, rename scenes according to new Locale settings.
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec unmount com.google.zxing.client.android-2 force
DEBUG/vending(639): [31] LocalAssetDatabase.notifyListener(): -7966251291516292305 / UNINSTALLED
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec unmount radioenergy.app-2 force
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec unmount de.android_telefonie.appmanager-1 force
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec unmount android.androidVNC-1 force
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec unmount org.cohortor.gstrings-2 force
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec unmount com.spritefish.fastburstcameralite-2 force
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec unmount com.twoplay.twoplayer-2 force
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec unmount com.easyshare.android-1 force
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec unmount com.domobile.efile-2 force
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec unmount com.google.android.apps.shopper-1 force
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): asec unmount org.openintents.filemanager-1 force
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): storage users /mnt/sdcard
WARN/ActivityManager(113): Killing processes unmount media at adjustment 0
WARN/ActivityManager(113): Killing ProcessRecord{46427398 1119:com.carlsberg.holta/10011} (adj 0): unmount media
DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(62): storage users /mnt/sdcard
INFO/WindowManager(113): WIN DEATH: Window{4670b0f0 com.carlsberg.holta/com.carlsberg.holta.send.ActivitySend paused=false}
ERROR/ActivityManager(113): fail to set top app changed!
DEBUG/AK8973(72): Compass Start
DEBUG/Sensors(113): open_akm, fd=33
```

Comment: The pictures from the gallery are saved on the SD card. When mounting, you're changing access from the phone to the desktop, so the phone can't see the SD card anymore.

Comment: Force stopping package de.android_telefonie.appmanager uid=10111 ... this is not the exception please provide the exception from logcat

Comment: @Luk  I get no exception for my app in the logcat. Updating my post with longer logcat list.

Comment: Updated my question with the manifest. Wanted to show the logcat output but it's not easy to copy that from logcat. but if anyone insist

Comment: check my edited answer hope its help you.

Comment: ok, lets try it, can you remove <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> from manifest file then also remove sdcard from your device and try to build again your app and run it. lets check the whats happen.. If you dont have a problem. thanks.

Comment: The behavior is most erratic. I remove the permission but see no difference. Testing... one time it's not crashing and one time when i mount the sd card my activity pop back up after vanicing. It's like android decide to Hide the activity when SD Card is not mounted. It's really brutal to. no OnPause, onStop or anything

Comment: See an open bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could probably find the problem other way round. Mount the phone and start your app..it will throw exception in your case. find the exception points from log cat. those are the reasons your activity was being killed.

Comment: yes i read one image from SD card and then my Activity stop accessing SD card. I have a GetView() in my BaseAdapter that grab the image. that's it. I dont even get an exception in logcat, just killed without even onDestroy(),pause, being called.

Comment: @Erik how can u be sure that ur activity stops accessing sdcard. getview method gets called multiple times due to some other operations as well. Why dont u test it in this way. put the image in resource folder and read it and see if ur activity still crashes after mounting the phone.

Comment: your right. It's working now. When i pulled down the notification menu to switch sd card to computer my Activity went onPause() and then onResume() and the getView() was called one more time. Im astonished i did not get any error exceptions not even in logcat that BitmapFactory.decodeStream hade failed so catastrophically

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeStream RETURNS The decoded bitmap, or null if the image data could not be decoded

Comment: then it's the new FileInputStream(file);...I have removed it and using
decodeResource and it's not crashing

Comment: Know i got the answer but why dont it work..The only trace from my killed Activity is the last line from the above logcat ..WIN DEATH: Wi....I think since non of the onPause, onStop, onDestroy is called my Actvity is still alive but GUI is lost in Android somewhere. Is here a way to look under the hood to see if my Activity is hanging around somewhere

Answer (score 2):

Is your application installed on the SD card?
Did you add the installLocation attribute to your manifest?
That might be the reason.

Comment: android:installLocation="internalOnly">

Comment: I can't think of anything other than the fact that maybe you're not closing an input stream to a file on the SD card and when you mount the SD card the OS decides to close your activity due to this...

Comment: your right in my getView() i did not close InputSream like input.close();. But doing it now made no difference however

Comment: Check that you don't have more places with open pointers to files in the SD card... Other than that my ideas have depleted